# "In this year" versus "this year"

Tags: prepositions, expressions

"In this year": Can anyone argue that the preposition *in* is unnecessary here, maybe even a hypercorrection? (Are there any situations where *in* is necessary?)

**Edits**

Some examples:

- How many days are left *in this year*? How many days are left *this year*?
- *In this year*, Tommy has grown 12 inches. *This year*, Tommy has grown 12 inches.

To stir up some debate, is *in this year* a prepositional phrase with *year* as the object? If so, how does this change with the phrase *this year*?

A construct such as "*In this year's* [some event], [this occurred]." makes sense because the phrase automatically becomes prepositional: *in the [event]* while *year's* becomes some kind of adjective. I'm not asking about this situation.

I suppose I'm interested in knowing whether *in this year* is grammatically correct. Can every sentence containing the phrase *in this year* be shortened to the one containing *this year*? (Do any grammar rules govern this?)

Comment: Please provide a specific sentence where you met this problem, otherwise it's too broad to answer for the ones who read your question.

Comment: @Alenanno I suppose I'm interested in knowing whether _in this year_ is grammatically correct. Can every sentence containing the phrase _in this year_ be shortened to the one containing _this year_?

Comment: yes it can, it's the same.

Comment: @nXqd Can you elaborate on this and put it in the answers?

Comment: Just off the top of my head it seems like "in" is used when you are talking about units of time. So you say "twelve months in a year", or as in your case days, but you would not normally say "I go on vacation twice in a year". But the lines are fairly blurry, and you could probably find exceptions to both cases.

Comment: @user1.2.3 'in' would be needed for the past. So speaking about some earlier event - "in this year the cup was won by...."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*In this year* is a prepositional phrase with *this year* as the object. *This year* by itself is a noun phrase.

Both can be used to place an event within the current year, but *this year* is much more natural. (I don't think *in this year* is a hypercorrection.)

> *In this year, Tommy has grown 12 inches.* (odd)
>
> *This year, Tommy has grown 12 inches.* (ok)

But if we're not talking about something happening but counting the number of days in a particular span of time, the preposition is necessary.

> *She left him this year.* (ok - *she left him* denotes an event)
>
> *How many days are left this year?* (very odd - *left* is an adjective)
>
> *How many days are left in this year?* (ok)

Expressions telling *when* are sometimes prepositional phrases (*during exams*), sometimes adverbs with or without modifiers (*later*, *very soon now*), and sometimes noun phrases (*next Tuesday*, *this year*).

Answer (score -2):

This, That, next, last and Every shouldn't be preceded by prepositions if they are followd by time words.
For eg. this year (correct)
        in this year (incorrect)
        next week (correct)
        in the next week (incorrect)

Comment: This categorical statement is incorrect. "Next week" and "in the next week" mean different things.